# Wait until a condition is met or timeout

Tags: go

I'm trying to write a function that break when a condition is met the output of command is equal something (hello in this example) in this case or 
timeout is reached

```
timeout := 10 sec

func run() error {

for {

    out , _ := exec.Command("echo", "hello").Output()
    if string(out) == "hello" || timeout  {
        break
    }
}

}
```

I've seen that folks use select but I don't know how to use it here, 
any hints?

Answer (score 10):

If the command runs quickly, then this simple approach might do:

```
deadline := time.Now().Add(10 * time.Second)
for {
    out, _ := exec.Command("echo", "hello").Output()
    if string(out) == "hello" || time.Now().After(deadline) {
        break
    }
}
```

An improvement is to use a [context with a timeout](https://godoc.org/context#WithTimeout):

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()
for {
    out, _ := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "echo", "hello").Output()
    if string(out) == "hello" || ctx.Err() != nil {
        break
    }
}
```

The context version will kill the command on timeout. The code loops until the string is found or [the context is done](https://godoc.org/context#Context.Err).

Comment: `exec.CommandContext`, right! That seems more concise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use a similar code than [Go by Example: Timeouts](https://gobyexample.com/timeouts)

```
c2 := make(chan string, 1) 
go func() {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    c2 <- "result 2"
}()
select {
case res := <-c2:
    fmt.Println(res)
case <-time.After(3 * time.Second):
    fmt.Println("timeout 2")
}
```

In your case, the `go func` would `exec` the `echo`, while the main function would wait for a timeout, or the execution of `go func`, whichever comes first.

That is: https://goplay.space/#MtHh3CenMcn

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c2 := make(chan string, 1)
    go func() {
        out, err := exec.Command("echo", "hello").Output()
        fmt.Println(err)
        c2 <- string(out)
    }()
    select {
    case res := <-c2:
        fmt.Println("'" + res + "'")
    case <-time.After(3 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("timeout 2")
    }
}
```

If the `echo` takes more than 3 seconds, the timeout would kick in.

Note that the example does not work i a playground setting, because:

```
"echo": executable file not found in $PATH
```

But in your local environment, it should work.

---

A different approach, based on context: https://goplay.space/#F2GtMLgVAAI

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    gen := func(ctx context.Context) <-chan string {
        dst := make(chan string)
        go func() {
            out, err := exec.Command("echo", "hello").Output()
            fmt.Println(err)
            for {
                select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    return // returning not to leak the goroutine
                case dst <- string(out):
                    return
                }
            }
        }()
        return dst
    }

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3)

    defer cancel() // cancel when we are finished consuming integers
    gen(ctx)
}
```

Comment: didn't understand, could please be more clear, how to adapt this to my need

Comment: @MelDev Sure: I have added an example.

Comment: in that case a better solution, imho, is to use context with timeout. Then attach the command instances to it. I suppose it will also handle the killing of the child process created previously if the timeout is reached.

Comment: @mh-cbon Do you mean `context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3)`? I have edited the answer to include that approach.

Comment: @VonC i want to break also if the output of the command equal to hello because the command could have multiple output value, What is the variable res in the example above ? and what is the c2 ? many thanks for u help

Comment: @MelDev Just variable names: change them to represent what you need in your case. You can adapt the proposed examples to add your loop/test/break case.

Comment: @mh-cbon OK. How about ThunderCat's version?